# angularjs table row editing issue

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to edit a row of data in a table.  When I click on the row it pops the required view but it cant pull the related data for editing. Can anyone try to find the issue. I guess its related to $routeParams and related index of table row. Added my plunker.

```html
app.controller("editController", ["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams", "listService", function($scope, $location, $routePartam, listService) { $scope.data = listService.getDepartments(); //$scope.id = $routeParams.id; //alert($route.current.params.id);
//alert("test"+ "$routeParams"); //$scope.Item=listService.getDepartments()[parseInt($routeParams.id)]; $scope.Item=listService.getDepartments()[0]; // saving an existing items $scope.save = function() { listService.editDepartments(0,{dialnumber:$scope.Item.dialnumber,department:$scope.Item.department,level:$scope.Item.level});
//listService.editDepartments(parseInt($routeParams.index),{dialnumber:$scope.Item.dialnumber,department:$scope.Item.department,level:$scope.Item.level}); //Saving code $location.path("/Items"); }; $scope.cancel = function() { $location.path("/Items");
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ez0s66S9bmO0jt8Nb6BR?p=info

Comment: You should format your code when posting, you'll have a better chance of someone scanning over it and spotting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you almost got it... it was a typo:

```
  function($scope, $location, $routePartam, listService) {
```

see? it says `$routePartam` instead or `$routeParams`, so your code for editController could be like this, check first line:

```
  function($scope, $location, $routeParams, listService) { 
    $scope.data = listService.getDepartments();
    //$scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    //alert($route.current.params.id);

    //alert("test"+ "$routeParams");
   //$scope.Item=listService.getDepartments()[parseInt($routeParams.id)];
   var id = $routeParams.id;  

    $scope.Item=listService.getDepartments()[id];
    // saving an existing items
    $scope.save = function() {
      listService.editDepartments(id,{dialnumber:$scope.Item.dialnumber,department:$scope.Item.department,level:$scope.Item.level});
```

check out the fixed plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oZrQaPUNTOOxDt8kqU5t?p=preview

Comment: thank you so much.. I didn't realize there was a typo